# Saying stuff out loud with baal koreh

Tags: torah-service, hefsek-interruption

I've seen people in shuls say stuff out loud with the baal koreh such as כאלה during pesach or לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו. This seems problematic if one has to hear torah reading on the tzibbur level from the klaf, and trei kolei lo mashmei. Should shul rabbis speak out against this the way they would speak against any other talking, or is it an acceptable practice"?

Comment: Do they?........

Comment: @ShmuelBrin People do (at least where I daven) sing certain words along with the man laining. Often it is the final words of the aliyah and other times it is well known phrases.

Comment: What is shuls, baal koreh, tzibbur, klaf, and  trei kolei lo mashmei [sic]? How do you know "one has to hear torah reading on the tzibbur level from the klaf"? What do you mean "one has to hear torah reading on the tzibbur level"? How do you know "trei kolei lo mashmei"? Why do you think missing a single word would be a problem? Consider clarifying all this.

Comment: @rosends where i daven certain people also talk during chazarat hashatz, leining, hallel, kaddish and pesukei dizimra.

Comment: @DoubleAA I see your point. Could the question then ask "should shul rabbis speak out against this the way they would speak against any other talking, or is it an acceptable practice"? It seems that there is a presupposition that the practice was deemed acceptable in the first place which explains (in the questioner's eyes) the lack of public statement against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our shul, the Baal Koreh pauses long enough for the tzibur to call out Ko'Ela!

Comment: Removed non-answer part of answer. I think this is an answer as in such a case it's not trei kolei.

Comment: But how do we know that this is the minhag and not just something weird the baal koreh does at your shul?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin  Shame - I found the edited-out part most amusing.